# Struggling with ambigous types in scala

Tags: scala

I am really struggling with ambigous types in scala...

I want to implement a StackManager which holds multiple stacks with different types... But something seems to be wrong.

```
object StackManager {

  val stacks = mutable.HashMap[String, mutable.Stack[_]]()
  def get[T](id: String): mutable.Stack[T] = {
    stacks.get(id) match {
      case Some(stack: mutable.Stack[T]) => stack
      case None => {
        val newStack = mutable.Stack[T]()
        stacks.put(id, newStack)
        newStack
      }
    }
  }
  def set[T](id: String, stack: mutable.Stack[T]) {
    stacks.put(id, stack)
  }
}
```

EDIT: With that I want to store different types of stacks in my manager:

```
StackManager.set[ClassA]("stack01", new mutable.Stack[ClassA]())
StackManager.set[ClassB]("stack02", new mutable.Stack[ClassB]())

StackManager.get[ClassA]("stack01") // returns the stack with type mutable.Stack[ClassA]
StackManager.get[ClassB]("stack02") // returns the stack with type mutable.Stack[ClassB]
```

EDIT2: scala version 2.9.2

Comment: Scala uses type erasure, so you can't write `Some(stack:mutable.Stack[T])`, you should use `Some(stack:mutable.Stack[_])` instead

Comment: And what would you want to do if your stacks.get(id) match matches the existing stack of different type (not T)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution, but it's a bit wonky. (quoting the output from Scala 2.10 console below, as a quick demo)

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe=>ru}
import scala.collection.mutable

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object StackManager {

  val stacks = mutable.HashMap[(String, ru.Type), mutable.Stack[_]]()
  def get[T:ru.TypeTag](id: String): mutable.Stack[T] = {
    stacks.get((id,ru.typeOf[T])) match {
      case Some(stack: mutable.Stack[T]) => stack
      case _ => {
        val newStack = mutable.Stack[T]()
        stacks.put((id,ru.typeOf[T]), newStack)
        newStack
      }
    }
  }
  def set[T:ru.TypeTag](id: String, stack: mutable.Stack[T]) {
    stacks.put((id,ru.typeOf[T]), stack)
  }
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined module StackManager

scala> StackManager.set("example", new mutable.Stack[String])

scala> StackManager.set("example", new mutable.Stack[Int])

scala> StackManager.get[Int]("example")
res15: scala.collection.mutable.Stack[Int] = Stack()

scala> StackManager.get[String]("example")
res16: scala.collection.mutable.Stack[String] = Stack()

scala> StackManager.get[Double]("example")
res17: scala.collection.mutable.Stack[Double] = Stack()
```

Less funky solution, without type tags:

```
object StackManager {

  val stacks = mutable.HashMap[String, mutable.Stack[_ <:Any]]()
  def get[T](id: String): mutable.Stack[T] = {
    stacks.get(id) match {
      case Some(stack: mutable.Stack[_]) => stack.asInstanceOf[mutable.Stack[T]]
      case _ => {
        val newStack = mutable.Stack[T]()
        stacks.put(id,newStack)
        newStack
      }
    }
  }
  def set[T](id: String, stack: mutable.Stack[T]) {
    stacks.put(id,stack)
  }
}
```

And it seems to do the type checking too:

```
scala> StackManager.set[String]("string",new mutable.Stack[String])

scala> StackManager.set[Integer]("integer",new mutable.Stack[String])
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.Stack[String]
 required: scala.collection.mutable.Stack[Integer]
              StackManager.set[Integer]("integer",new mutable.Stack[String])

scala> StackManager.set[Integer]("integer",new mutable.Stack[Integer])

scala> StackManager.get[Integer]("integer")
res11: scala.collection.mutable.Stack[Integer] = Stack()
```

I haven't tried it in scala 2.9 though.

Comment: Sorry but u obviously misunderstood me :( 
I dont need the Type mixed in the id for the key of the stack HashMap. The problem with mutable.Stack[_] is I get an "unbound wildcard type error. Scala version is 2.9.2

Comment: I have just edited my answer, see the next variant which seems to be closer to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Because type parameters are not stored while executing scala on the JVM, you need to store that types by yourself, if you need. For example,

```
val stacks = mutable.HashMap[String, (Class, mutable.Stack[_])]()
```

and then check if that `Class` equals to what is requested.
But this probably isn't what you want: stacks will be overwritten with stacks of different types. But you get the idea, and can invent something that works.

Comment: Well that looks even more strange.... :D 
Actually I want to use `StackManager.set[ClassA]("stack01", new mutable.Stack[ClassA])` as well as `StackManager.set[ClassB]("stack02", new mutable.Stack[ClassB])` 

With other words I want to store different types of Stacks...

Answer (score 0):

I found a suitable solution:

```
object StackManager {

  val stacks = mutable.HashMap[String, S forSome {type S}]()
  def get[S](id: String): S = {
    stacks.get(id) match {
      case Some(stack) => stack.asInstanceOf[S]
      case None => null.asInstanceOf[S]
    }
  }
  def set[S](id: String, stack: S) {
    stacks.put(id, stack)
  }
}


StackManager.set[mutable.Stack[ClassA]]("stack01", new mutable.Stack[ClassA]())
StackManager.set[mutable.Stack[ClassB]]("stack02", new mutable.Stack[ClassB]())

StackManager.get[mutable.Stack[ClassA]]("stack01") // returns the stack with type mutable.Stack[ClassA]
StackManager.get[mutable.Stack[ClassB]]("stack02") // returns the stack with type mutable.Stack[ClassB]
```

Any improvement ideas?
Some kind of type check on mutable.Stack would be great...